# jQuery live function is not, well, functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm generating content using Ajax and therefore need to use `.live()` to attach a function to the click event on links generated. It doesn't seem to be working unfortunately, and I'm not sure why. I've tried putting it both inside and outside of the domready context; no luck. It was working when I was simply using `$('a').click()`, but that didn't work on the links pulled from Ajax. Any thoughts?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#content a').live('click', function(){
        var moveIt = $("#content").outerWidth();
        alert(moveIt);
        $('#content').animate({'maxWidth': '+=' + moveIt / 2 + 'px', 'left': '6%'}, 'slow');
    });

    $('a.back').live('click',function(){
        $('#content').animate({'maxWidth': '360px', 'left' : '43%'}, 400);
    });
});
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<section id="content" class="textiles"><!--content start-->
<div id="ajax-container">
    <div id="ajax-content"><!--test-->
        <h1>Installations</h1>
        <a rel="bookmark" href="http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/installations/light-fixtures" title="light&nbsp;fixtures"><img src="http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/images/51t.jpg" alt="Seating Area with Light Fixtures" height="64" width="140"></a>
        <a rel="bookmark" href="http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/installations/scad-fibers-installation" title="SCAD fibers&nbsp;installation"><img src="http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/images/49t.jpg" alt="Installation in Context" height="64" width="140"></a>
        <a rel="bookmark" href="http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/installations/other-gallery" title="fashion 2008&nbsp;photoshoot"><img src="http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/images/47t.jpg" alt="fashion's backdrop" height="64" width="140"></a>
        <a rel="bookmark" href="http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/installations/qp2-creative-gallery" title="QP2 Creative&nbsp;Gallery"><img src="http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/images/41t.jpg" alt="QP2 Creative gallery" title=""></a>
        </div>
    </div><!--end ajax container-->
</section><!--end content-->
```

Comment: @maniator I'll update the question with it.

Comment: Put this into jsfiddle and it certainly [does something](http://jsfiddle.net/NZUvT/) on click.  What's not working?

Comment: There's no need to put your `.live()` calls inside of `$(document).ready(function() {})`. See: http://encosia.com/2010/08/18/dont-let-jquerys-document-ready-slow-you-down/

Comment: @justkt None of the events that are supposed to be triggered are activating. It did work in your fiddle, but I don't know why it's not working on the live site.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @qp2wd - I'm figuring since it worked in the fiddle there is something in the code that you are not showing us (perhaps the success method from the ajax call) that isn't working.  Does the HTML that you posted here match what you see in something like firebug?

Comment: @justkt @tomalak Here's a link to the live site. What's supposed to happen is when any `a` in #content is clicked, #content expands to suit the width of the data being pulled in by ajax. When `.back` is clicked, it slides back to its original width. Here's the live page so you can see what I'm talking about http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/installations/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JavaScript code inside the *body tag* is messing up with the script inside the *head tag*. In your *body tag* a *click binding* "**return false**". and this stops calling any "click" bindings further.

I found three problems in your code. After correcting it I got the alert box.

1. wrapped your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ });` just like you have in your question (but it's not in the demo site).
2. on the `relink: function() {` in your *body tag* - commented "**return false;**" and
3. corrected the semicolon missing in
   **smd_ajax.spinit(1);**

   ```
   if ((site_url.indexOf(url.host) >= 0) && (bindit == true)) {
       smd_ajax.spinit(1); //HERE 3rd Edit.
       jQuery(this).unbind();
       smd_ajax.grab(this.href);
       //return false; //HERE 2nd Edit.
   }
   ```

You can use `preventDefault();` to stop the default behaviour.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#content a').live('click', function(e){
        var moveIt = $("#content").outerWidth();
        alert(moveIt);
        $('#content').animate({'maxWidth': '+=' + moveIt / 2 + 'px', 'left': '6%'}, 'slow');
        e.preventDefault(); //Hyperlink won't load page link.
    });
    $('a.back').live('click',function(){
       $('#content').animate({'maxWidth': '360px', 'left' : '43%'}, 400);
    });
});
```

Comment: I could kiss you sir! That worked beautifully. I'll have to mention this solution to the gentleman who created the plugin I'm using for Ajax to see if your fix conflicts with something else in the script, though it seems to be going splendidly so far. A thousand times thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at `.delegate()`? It does nearly the same thing as `.live()` but allows you to specify an additional selector to filter any triggered elements.

```
$('#content').delegate('a', 'click', function() {
  // code here
}
```

Not sure why your particular example isn't working, but if you have at least jQuery 1.4.2, try updating to `.delegate()`.

Comment: I took a look at `.delegate()`, but wanted to see if I could get `.live()` working. Trying it now... And no dice. Here's a link to the live site; maybe there's some other jquery affecting it? http://www.qp2creative.com/clients/dfrank/installations/

Comment: What do you mean by not working? I'm able to click on an image and go back just fine. Is there something else it should be doing?

And it's better to use `.delegate()` over `.live()` if possible if you don't need to bubble all the way up the DOM tree.

Comment: I should mention that I'm using Firfox 3.6, so maybe you're encountering some odd browser issue.

Comment: It's not the functionality that's the problem-- clicking to go forward and back does work. What's supposed to happen is there's supposed to be an alert letting me know the width of #content followed by #content expanding to suit the width of the data being pulled in by ajax. That's what's failing to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your site - I can't really explain your alert not working, but it seems the ajax implementation is a bit convoluted. I think you might be able to simplify it and avoid the weird delegate/live problem altogether.

Have you considered using a simple jQuery.ajax or jQuery.load function to change your dynamic content? I know those functions have callbacks that let you run subsequent "success" functions after your ajax call is completed. Perhaps one of those callbacks would be a good place to run your resizing function?

Comment: The ajax is complex because it's being implemented via a plugin for the CMS I'm using-- my knowledge of jquery is barely novice level, and my knowledge of ajax lower than that, so the plugin was much easier for me to wrap my head around. Wrapping the resizing function into the success callback isn't a bad idea; if it involves if/else, though, it might end up being  a little too complex for my skill level.